# C++ While loop to get Number in an Interval

Tags: c++, intervals

How would you make a program that if a number is not in an interval ex [-10,100) to subtract 1 if it is over it until it is in the interval or add one until it is in the interval
//check if number is in range

[image]

Comment: It just a combination of while loops and if statements. For example use an if statements to decide if the number is below the internal or above the interval. Then use two different while loops depending on what you found.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Copy and paste your code next time.

Answer (score 1):

Same spirit as cigien's answer but without c++17:

```cpp
auto r = std::max(-10, std::min(x, 99));
```

Comment: The answer was wrong. Now that it's corrected, I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for this. Just use [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp):

```
auto result = std::clamp(number, -10, 99);
```

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to c++, how would you implement it into code

Comment: I don't understand. That's it. Take `number` from the user, and print `result`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by use of conditional and iterative statements easily. i.e. using `loops` and `if` can solve your issue.

the code goes as follows:

```
for(int i = yourNumber; i < lowerRange && i > upperRange; ){
  if(i < lowerRange)
      i++;
  else if(i > upperRange)
      i--;
  else
      cout<< i << "is in range";
}
//you can assign the value of i to the 'yourNumber' variable to change its initial value.
```